# ImportError: Could not import settings '1 '

Tags: django

When creating a new project produces here is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py", line 5 , in <module>
      management.execute_from_command_line ()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399 , in execute_from_command_line
      utility.execute ()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392 , in execute
      self.fetch_command (subcommand). run_from_argv (self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 261 , in fetch_command
      commands = get_commands ()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 107 , in get_commands
      apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 54 , in __ getattr__
      self._setup (name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 49 , in _setup
      self._wrapped = Settings (settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 132 , in __ init__
      % (Self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings '1 '(Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named 1
```

What is wrong with the variable SETTINGS_MODULE. Everything worked fine until I got to put these packages

```
migajek-django-tastypie-jqgrid
six
python-dateutil-2.2
django-tastypie-0.11.0
```

after installing this and the trouble happened

Comment: why are you putting in the version numbers in the settings ? I am assuming this is the INSTALLED_APPS settings ?